# How to get the address from Google Maps Geolocation API if we have only one wifiAccessPoints

Tags: google-geolocation

Google Maps Geolocation API documentation says that :
wifiAccessPoints array must contain two or more WiFi access point objects.

So, how can we get the address from Google Maps Geolocation API if we have only one wifiAccessPoint.

Any help appreciated.
~RD

Comment: I have the same question. Any answer? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Pass as a single element in the array wifiAccessPoints[]